# R: Reticulate conda_create() does not create a new environment at the specified miniconda path

Tags: r, conda, miniconda, reticulate

I have installed miniconda in a specified filedrive;

```
install_miniconda(path = "D:/miniconda", update = T)

* Miniconda has been successfully installed at "D:/miniconda".
[1] "D:/miniconda"
```

The environment path environment points to the wrong folder so I update this;

```
miniconda_path()
[1] "C:/Users/OEM/AppData/Local/r-miniconda"

Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_MINICONDA_PATH = "D:/miniconda")
miniconda_path()
[1] "D:/miniconda"
```

And now I want to create a new environment however this defaults back to the wrong drive / folder? Why?

```
> conda_list()
          name                                       python
1     Anaconda                      D:\\Anaconda/python.exe
2         base                     D:\\miniconda/python.exe
3 r-reticulate D:\\miniconda\\envs\\r-reticulate/python.exe

> conda_create(envname = "my_new_env", conda = "D:/miniconda/_conda.exe")
+ "D:/miniconda/_conda.exe" "create" "--yes" "--name" "my_new_env" "python=3.9" "--quiet" "-c" "conda-forge"

...

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
[1] "C:\\Users\\OEM\\.conda\\envs\\my_new_env/python.exe"
Warning messages:
1: In conda_binary(conda) :
  Supplied path is not a conda binary: ‘D:/miniconda/_conda.exe’
2: In conda_binary(conda) :
  Supplied path is not a conda binary: ‘D:/miniconda/_conda.exe’
3: In conda_binary(conda) :
  Supplied path is not a conda binary: ‘D:/miniconda/_conda.exe’
4: In conda_binary(conda) :
  Supplied path is not a conda binary: ‘D:/miniconda/_conda.exe’
```

We can see that it created the environment in the C drive even though I've specified everything to be in the D drive. Also for some reason I'm getting a warning message that the path is not a conda binary? [I've followed the steps of this tutorial which creates the environment in the exact same way](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/04/getting-started-with-python-using-r-and-reticulate/) and if I look into the folder _conda.exe does exist. So what's going on?
[snippet of folder showing _conda.exe exists in the D drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mof8U.png)